# How to set time for my screen saver to get activated in MAC yosemite from Command line

Tags: osx-yosemite

I want to set time in start after check box of Desktop and Screensaver settings in system preferences. But i wanted to do it from my command lime. changing the values of com.apple.screensaver.plist didnot helped me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I googled a lot and found this                                                           "$defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime n". But it is of no help.                                                                                                               Reference : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166624/programmatically-change-screen-saver-start-after-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrote $defaults, then thats the problem. The following sets the screensaver to activate after one hour:

```
macbook:~ user$ defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime 3600
```

Note that you must quit the System Preferences application before changing the property, otherwise it is not set.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. But i want to set through commandline because i am doing for remote system. I need to add this in script which will run in root login.  This command is working fine in $ prompt but not in # prompt